# Regex expression wont match

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to replace portions of a `textarea` text by regex.

`propertiesText` is the full text received from the `textarea`, and the replacement code is as follows:

```
var propertyName = inputs[i].name;
var propertyValue = inputs[i].value;

//#regexExpression = #propertyName=.* [example: /#EPCDatabase\/EPCdatabase.param\/epc.db.user=.*$/gim]//
var regexExpression = new RegExp(propertyName + "=.*$","gim");
//#newString = propertyName=propertyValue [example: EPCDatabase\/EPCdatabase.param\/epc.db.user=ddddd]//
var newString = propertyName.substring(1) + "=" + propertyValue;
console.log("Regex Expression: " + regexExpression);
console.log("Replace String: " + newString);

propertiesText.replace(regexExpression, newString);
console.log(propertiesText);
return;
```

In the console, I'm getting the following regex expression:

[image: Console Regex]

But the text is not being replaced in the original `propertiesText`:

[image: Properties String after replace]

I've tried checking my regex and [you can see it is matching](https://regex101.com/r/31CLvX/2).

I've also tried isolating the replacement code part with the same regex which is outputted, and [as you can see again](https://jsfiddle.net/Alon_A/082kyqz9/1/), its working.

What am I missing in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String Replace doesnt acutally update the current string, but simply returns a new string with the replace applied. So to fix your code update to

```
propertiesText = propertiesText.replace(regexExpression, newString);
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

> The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

Comment: Damn me (blushing), I was suspecting the replacement inst actually replacing, but i was too blind thinking the Regex was the issue. Only thing left is to say a big **Thank you**.